# Can't Delete a Scheduled Task Folder With Quotes in the Name

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm messing around with some scripted task scheduler automation for a project. However, I made the mistake of creating a new Task Scheduler folder with quotes around it.

[image]

However, when I follow the proper `Right Click > Delete Folder` option, I'm met with this error dialog:

[image]

I tried to reboot and remove, but this didn't help. My google-fu fails me sometimes, and in this case, all I can seem to find is "how to delete a scheduled task with quotes in the name", not a folder. How can I remove this folder? It's fairly out of the way, and it's highly likely I'll never see it in the future, but it's bugging me in the moment, so I'd like to know!

Comment: See [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454115/where-does-windows-store-the-settings-for-scheduled-tasks-console/20454183) on where scheduled task information is stored.  Fix it by hand.

Comment: That did the trick, but the only location I found it was in the registry under `Schedule>TaskCache>Tree`. You can either make that an answer, or mark this as a dupe. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454115/where-does-windows-store-the-settings-for-scheduled-tasks-console/20454183)  on where scheduled task information is stored.

**Fix it by hand.**

**Kaizerwolf** pointed out that they found the exact solution in the registry under:

`Schedule>TaskCache>Tree.`

I ***would have*** marked this as a duplicate but I don't think I can do that when StackOverflow is the source and people can still look this up here.